# Equivalent of max and over(partition by) in R for flattening

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have data as:

```
ID  time0       obs_num recorded_dt day0    day1    day2    day3    day4    day5    ... day31
1   2009-01-01  A       2009-01-01  A       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ... NULL
1   2009-01-01  D       2009-01-31  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ... D
1   2009-01-01  B       2009-01-05  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    B       ... NULL
2   2005-02-02  B       2005-02-03  NULL    B       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ... NULL
```

Data can be reproduced as:

```r
example = data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2),
  time0 = c('2009-01-01','2009-01-01','2009-01-01','2005-02-02'),
  obs_num = c('A','D','B','B'),
  recorded_dt = c('2009-01-01','2009-01-31','2009-01-05','2005-02-03')
)

library(tidyverse)
df <- example %>% 
  mutate(difs_days = floor(difftime(recorded_dt, time0, units="days"))) %>% 
  arrange(difs_days) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = difs_days, values_from = obs_num, names_prefix = 'day') %>% 
  arrange(ID, recorded_dt)

df
# # A tibble: 4 × 7
#      ID time0      recorded_dt day0  day1  day4  day30
#   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 2009-01-01 2009-01-01  A     NA    NA    NA   
# 2     1 2009-01-01 2009-01-05  NA    NA    B     NA   
# 3     1 2009-01-01 2009-01-31  NA    NA    NA    D    
# 4     2 2005-02-02 2005-02-03  NA    B     NA    NA
```

I want to flatten the data into:

```
ID  time0       day0    day1    day2    day3    day4    day5    ... day31
1   2009-01-01  A       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    B       ... D
2   2005-02-02  NULL    B       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ... NULL
```

In SQL, I would use max(dayX) over(partition by ID) as XYZ and then keep distinct values.
I think there must be an efficient way in R. Can you please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[
  , recorded_dt:=NULL][
  , lapply(.SD, \(x) sort(x, na.last = TRUE, decreasing = TRUE)[1])
  , by=.(ID, time0)]
##    ID      time0 day0 day1 day4 day30
## 1:  1 2009-01-01    A <NA>    B     D
## 2:  2 2005-02-02 <NA>    B <NA>  <NA>
```

The internal variable `.SD` represents a subset of the `data.table` including all columns except those included in the `by=...` clause. This is why we have to remove the column `recorded_dt` first.

Comment: Added a few more columns to the by clause as needed. This worked for me well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can summarise multiple columns with `across()`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(ID, time0) %>%
  summarise(across(day0:day30, ~ if(all(is.na(.x))) NA else max(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 2 × 6
#      ID time0      day0  day1  day4  day30
#   <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 2009-01-01 A     NA    B     D    
# 2     2 2005-02-02 NA    B     NA    NA
```

Comment: I received an error stating Error in `summarise()` .... caused by error in `across()`

Comment: @PrajwalManiPradhan `df` in my code is not the `example` object, but the reproduced data created from your code. Don't pass `example` to my code directly.

Comment: Your code is giving me the desired output but it also gives a warning: stack imbalance in 'lapply'. Is there a way to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Update:

For the given example we could use: `summarise(across(everything(), ~trimws(paste(., collapse = ''))))`

To replace `""` by `NA` just add `na_if("")`at the end of the code:

```
library(dplyr)

example %>%
  select(-recorded_dt) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.na(.), "", .))) %>% 
  group_by(ID, time0) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~trimws(paste(., collapse = '')))) %>% 
  na_if("")
```

```
     ID time0      day0  day1  day4  day30
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 2009-01-01 "A"   ""    "B"   "D"  
2     2 2005-02-02 ""    "B"   ""    ""
```

Comment: received an warning stating `funs()` was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0. Please use a list of either functions or lambdas ...

Comment: No problem. I will update it. it is only a warning.

Comment: Nice work! But I think it's better to convert `""` back to `NA` if the data will be used to a further analysis. `NA` is R means something is missing, but `""` is a character object.

Comment: Is there a way to preserve the date format? Also, when I added the na_if I received a stack imbalance warning.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that other strings variables in my data were concatenated. Is there a way to solve this? For example, the name variable was concatenated as 'Dave Dave', zip was concatenated as '2081420814'.

Comment: Should I include name and zip in the group by statement.